# Brackets after Theorems, Propositions... with amsthm, potential conflict with another package

Tags: amsthm

I need to use the class indicated ([you may find it here](https://pubsonline.informs.org/pb-assets/LaTeX/MNSC-style-file-2023-1698680974400.zip)) for a paper submission. However, this class has a weird syntax for the proofs in Theorems, Propositions, etc. (this is a known fact.) The usual fix is as indicated below, but this time I am getting two brackets after every Theorem, Proposition, etc. as shown in the image. I tried moving around the order of the \let's and the \usepackage{amsthm} without success. I appreciate any help.

[image]

```
\documentclass[mnsc,blindrev]{informs4}
\let\proof\relax 
\let\endproof\relax 
\let\theoremstyle\relax 
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{comment}

\TheoremsNumberedThrough 
\ECRepeatTheorems
\EquationsNumberedThrough 

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}
The sum of the areas of the two squares on the legs ($a$ and $b$) equals the area of the square on the hypotenuse ($c$).
\end{theorem}

\begin{proof}
Just because.
\end{proof}


\end{document}
```

Comment: It would help us to help you, if we would know, where to get the class from. Also it would be help us to help you, if you would show not only a code snippet but a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/277964), that can be copied to reproduce your problem and get exactly the result of the screenshot you've shown. So I would suggest to edit the question and add the missing information. However, if you are required to use this class, you should probably not change it too much so as not to make the editor's work unnecessarily difficult. I know publishers who simply rej

Comment: Also, if you have been asked to use a specific class to submit a manuscript, don't start changing the lauourt or look this this. It is often a wast of time. They probably have their reasons for setting up the class like they do.

Comment: Thank you @cabohah, I just edited the post.

Comment: The class uses the (obsolete) `theorem` package. That's what they want, don't load `amsthm`.